# How do I check if substring is out of bounds?

Tags: apex, string, substring

I'm trying to find a way to check if a substring causes an out of bounds error in an If statement

This is what I have got so far but if the original string has less than 8 characters after substring then I will get an error.

```
String s = 'This is M-000034'; // if this was M-0023 it will cause error
Boolean replied = false;
String subs = 'M-';

If(s.containsIgnoreCase(subs)){
String s1 = s.toUpperCase();
String s2 = s1.deleteWhitespace();
system.debug(s1);
system.debug(s2);
replied = true;
system.debug(replied);
Integer r = s2.indexOf(subs);
String caseNumber = s2.substring(r, r+8);
system.debug(caseNumber);

}else {
system.debug('nothing');
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the length() method of the String class? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic bounds-overflow bug. Before you take a fixed-length substring or request a specific string index, you must check whether the string contains enough characters to respond to the request.

In this case, you can either use the one-argument version of `String.substring()`, which starts at the specified index and goes to the end of the string, or you can do some simple arithmetic with a ternary expression:

```
String caseNumber = s2.substring(r, r+8 > s2.length() ? s2.length() : r+8);
```

The ternary operator (`?:`) is the only three-argument operator in Apex and most other C/Java family languages. Basically it works like this:

```
<boolean expresssion> ? <true value> : <false value>
```

It evaluates the boolean expression and then returns either the true value or the false value as appropriate. It's a terse, expression-based form of an `if` conditional. Here, we use it to check if the string is too short to take `r+8` characters. If it is, we just go to the end of the string; otherwise, we take `r+8` characters.

Comment: Thanks it works! not quite understanding what's happening after r+8..

Comment: Added a little more explanation on the ternary operator.